# getting Null value + probably query isn't working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

Actually I'm following mvc-3 tier architecture to my application.and here is my Search option's implementation.
In my servlet(controller) I'm doing this :

```
        String select = request.getParameter("select");  // getting value
        String search = request.getParameter("search");  // getting value
        request.setAttribute("select", select);
        request.setAttribute("search", search);
        System.out.println("Select : "+select+" Search : "+search);

        int page = 1;
        int recordsPerPage = 20;
        if(request.getParameter("page") != null)
            page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
        SearchDAO searchDAO=new SearchDAO();
        List<User> list1=searchDAO.searchAllUsers((page-1)*recordsPerPage,recordsPerPage,select,search);  //getting null value,doing SOP of list1
        int noOfRecords = searchDAO.getNoOfRecords();  //getting null value,doing SOP
        int noOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(noOfRecords * 1.0 / recordsPerPage);  //getting null value,doing SOP
        session.setAttribute("noOfRecords", noOfRecords);
        request.setAttribute("searchList", list1);
        request.setAttribute("noOfPages", noOfPages);
        request.setAttribute("currentPage", page);
```

and in the SearchDAO is:

```
public class SearchDAO {
private int noOfRecords;
Connection connection;
Statement stmt;

    public List<User> searchAllUsers(int offset ,int noOfRecords,String select,String search){
    private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException{
    Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
    return con;  //ConnectionFactory is class for making the connection to DB.
}
     String query="select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from info where '"+select+
"' like '%"+search+"%' order by serialNo asc limit 
" + offset + " , " + noOfRecords;

    List<User> list1 = new ArrayList<User>();
    User user1=null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
        user1=new User();
        user1.setSerial(rs.getInt(1));
            user1.setName(rs.getString(2));
            user1.setEmail(rs.getString(3));
            list1.add(user1);
            }

        rs.close();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
        if(rs.next())
            this.noOfRecords = rs.getInt(1); 

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally
    {
        try {
            if(stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            if(connection != null)
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return list1;

}

public int getNoOfRecords() {
    return noOfRecords;
}
}
```

- Editted
  Feel free to comment & please rectify me if I'm not following the proper mvc architecture.

Comment: Which line specific returns the `nullpointerexception`? As this is probably a uninitialized variable that you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

- check if you are able to retrieve parameters in your
  request.getParameter(); call in your servlet
- check if you are able to store parameters in request scope like
  request.setAttribute() call

Comment: check his DAO, he's trying to getParameter on null reference .

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is right,:

```
'%"+request.getParameter("search)+"%'
```

1. Firstly, you never initialized request in SearchDAO, and you are
   calling getParameter on its instance, Thus NullPointerException
2. Secondly, how would your seachDAO get the request ??, it isnt a
   servlet, its just aplain POJO

Comment: thanks for you input; For 1> I'm checking and for 2> It's simple a java class(am I doing any wrong here after seeing the code). :(

Comment: @bigzero you cant get request parameters in a simple java file. it should bea servlet,the better approac would be to pass your request parameters as argumenmts to yourmethod in your DAO.

Comment: then what will be the datatype of request.getParameter("something") in argument

Comment: @bigzero whats the data type of something ?

Comment: could you tell me that which one is right : /'%"+search+"%'/ or /'%'"+search+"'%'/ ?

Comment: thanks, and get rid of that error,but now I'm getting NoOfRecords, NoOfPages,List values show null,...any reason - why?

Comment: and I'm also using the same concept for select all values,only difference is the query->but that's working properly

Comment: @bigzero i am sorry, i ma kinda bust atm .. ll lookinto your problem in a bit :)

Comment: ..GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR ok //

Comment: On this Question context I have raised another Question, And the main issue I found that rs unable to int the while loop,and here is the link,if possible you can take a look of it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606815/getting-null-value-from-attribute

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, create a bean class and with the help of the class, you can communicate between controller and DAO, you could not do it by using request.getAttribute(which is in your DAO).