# resultset isn't going into while loop and set the value

Tags: java, servlets

Observing a strange behavior of this piece of code,because resultset is not giving the null value(doing SOP it's clear)but not going into while loop(that is quite strange!)and it's simple dao class,*it's not able to set the value in user object*:

```
public class DAO{

 public List<User> searchAllUsers(int offset ,int noOfRecords, String column, String value){
    String query="select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from info where '"+column+"' like '%"+value+"%' order by serialNo asc limit " + offset + "  ,  " + noOfRecords;
    //  String query="select * from info where '"+select+"' like '%"+search+"%' order by serialNo asc";
    System.out.println("1");
    List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    User user=null;

    try {
        System.out.println("b4 Connection");
        connection = getConnection();
        System.out.println("After Connection");
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Create statement");
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        if(rs!=null)
        System.out.println("1> Hi rs:"+rs);
        while(rs!= null && rs.next()){
            System.out.println("hi...!!");
            user=new User();
            user.setSerial(rs.getInt(1));
            System.out.println("Serial : "+rs.getInt(1));
            user.setName(rs.getString(2));
            user.setEmail(rs.getString(3));
            user.setImei(rs.getString(4));
            System.out.println("I'm here !");
            user.setModel(rs.getString(5));
            user.setManufacturer(rs.getString(6));
            user.setOsversion(rs.getString(7));
            user.setHdyk(rs.getString(8));
            user.setDate(rs.getString(9));
            user.setAppname(rs.getString(10));
            list.add(user);
            System.out.println("Last..");
            }
        rs.close();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
        System.out.println("2> :" +rs);
        if(rs.next()){
            this.noOfRecords = rs.getInt(1); 
        System.out.println("3> :" +this.noOfRecords);
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      finally
    {
        try {
            if(stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            if(connection != null)
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return list;

}

public int getNoOfRecords() {
    return noOfRecords;
}
}
```

And it corresponding output is :

```
1
b4 Connection
After Connection
Create statement
1> Hi rs:com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@35e6e3
2> :com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@c9630a
3> :0
```

Even I'm also using the same code like it for select All user's and that point of time I'm getting proper o/p.

Spending so many hours for it,but unable to resolve it-where I'm going wrong....so your review & comment will be always welcome.

Comment: Ouch. Learn about prepared statements if you don't want to be attcked by a SQL injection attack: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Just on a side note: Why don't you use a debugger instead of "echo what I've done" `System.out.println()` calls? It would make your life so much easier it's hard to find words for it to be accurately escribed.

Comment: @ppeterka, to be frank how to use debugger in this context.

Comment: What do you mean? Set breakpoints, start server, issue request, wait for debugger to interrupt execution, observe variables in the critical points. Just the usual stuff. (If the server is run remotely, you will have to connect the debugger to the server)

Comment: @user1645434: just like in every other context. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of the method, execute the code in debug mode until it reaches the breakpoint, then step through the lines to see what gets executed and inspect the variables to see what they contain.

Comment: ok,but there is a simple thing if I change my query **"select * from info where '"+column+"' like '%"+value+"%' order by serialNo asc";** even at that time the o/p is same....here is my questain why?what makes the preparedStatement different for the sake of  o/p perspective.

Comment: The query returns nothing. That means it's not the right query, or that the data you're looking for doesn't exist in the database. A prepared statement won't change anything. But concatenating values like you're doing is not robust and insecure. You should use a prepared statements with parameters: `select * from info where '"+column+"' like ? order by serialNo asc`.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: @JBNizet one more thing that is in my query,dynamically my 'column' and according to that 'value' is taken,Now I'm using preparedStatement then whenever my search query will be fired then how do I know it's row index?? as I'm searching for this condition 'where column like %value%"'-how do I set it's rowIndex ??

Comment: @ppeterka,@JBNizet  I found where I was going wrong :) :),actually I was giving the column name like '"+column+"' ,but when I give the actual name i.e email;it's shows the result,but why it's not taking the dynamic fetched value same it's column name.any reason...if you know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your `query` didn't fetch you any row. And hence `rs.next()` will return `false`, hence the execution will not go into the `while loop`:

```
while(rs!= null && rs.next())
```

And you don't have to check for `rs != null`. It won't be null. The `stmt.executeQuery` always returns a `ResultSet`. Just have `rs.next()` in your `while`:

```
while(rs.next())
```

And yes, you should use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for executing your `query` rather than `Statement`. Here's a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) which will help you get started.

Comment: but it's showing **Hi rs:com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@35e6e3**

Comment: @user1645434.. It will show that, because it's the value of `ResultSet` reference. It will not be null. See my updated answer.

Comment: dont mind,but ....you will the  actually the complete questain was posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600785/getting-null-value-probably-query-isnt-working ,so could you take a look of it ,..any suggestion if I have to change the code

Comment: @user1645434.. One suggestion I have already suggested. Use PreparedStatement instead of `Statement`. Then get your code to work. And then you can see whether you can improve on it.

Comment: one more thing that is in my query,dynamically my 'column' and according to that 'value' is taken,Now I'm using preparedStatement then whenever my search query will be fired then how do I know it's row index?? as I'm searching for this condition 'where column like %value%"'-how do I set it's rowIndex ??

Comment: @user1645434. What? I couldn't understand what are you saying. Are you asking how to set the value for `value`?

Comment: see, now my query is like **select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from info where '"+column+"' like ? order by serialNo asc limit " +offset+ "  , "+noOfRecords ** now I'm setting value **ps.setString(parameterIndex, value)**; ... how could I or how do will I know that what will be my parameterindex ?

Comment: Why are you having both `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `*` there in SELECT? And also, you should set values for all the parameters there.

Comment: Please go through the tutorial link I gave to learn `PreparedStatement`. You can't just get through it in one go. First understand how it works. And then if you can't get it solved come back with a new question.

Comment: how should I set values for all parameters there....? please guide that how do I do this .

Comment: Go to this tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html I can't just explain everything here. Please also read my previous comment.

Comment: If the query is **"select * from info where '"+column+"' like '"+value+"' limit " + offset + "  ,  " + noOfRecords;** it's also showing the same o/p mentioned in Ques :(

Comment: I found where I was going wrong :) :),actually I was giving the column name like '"+column+"' ,but when I give the actual name i.e email;it's shows the result,but why it's not taking the dynamic fetched value same it's column name.any reason...if you know?

Comment: You were giving `column` inside a `single quotes`. So, your substitution became - `'email'` instead of `email`.

Comment: Try using this: - `"select * from info where "+column+" like '"+value+"' limit " + offset + " , " + noOfRecords;`

Comment: Works :):):) ,thanks for your patience as bored all the times by my so silly Ques  & comments.don't get me wrong.

Comment: @user1645434.. Ah! It's not problem. Never hesitate to get your problems solved. Of course there is no one whom you know personally here. We all here help others on our wish only. So, nothing to bother. And you're welcome :)